# made many progress

Tags: phrase-usage

Initially I wanted to speak "made a lot of progress", but my tongue somehow slipped and it became "made many progress" - I am a bit uneasy whether it is natural in English.

Is "made many progress" natural and proper in English?

> the hypothesis has been substantiated by many facts.
> It's obvious we have **made many progress**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was nothing really wrong with *a lot of progress* although some people think it is too informal for writen language. However your unease is justified as *much progress* would have been correct. You would have used *many* if it preceded a plural noun.